# Linkar recursos, como CSS, dentro da estrutura de um site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sou iniciante e estou enfrentando problemas com linkar os scripts, CSS e imagens. Tenho a seguinte estrutura em pastas do meu site, só um exemplo:

```
- Pasta Raiz    
  --cadastro  
    --- cadastro.html
  --images  
    --- icon.png  
  --script  
    --- script.js  
  --style  
    --- cabecalho.css
  index.html
```

Supondo que todas as paginas do meu site tenham cabeçalho igual, então eu teria que importar para todas elas o CSS `cabeçalho.css`. Para a página inicial é fácil.

Mas para chamar esse mesmo css na pagina `cadastro.html`? No meu ponto de vista, para o `cadastro.html` o estilo `cabecalho.css` não existe, queria saber como linkar eles, porque é uma completa desorganização deixar todas as suas páginas na pasta raiz.

Comment: Dica: ver o código fonte de páginas alheias é essencial para aprender programação web (todo browser tem essa funcionalidade).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/cabecalho.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/cabecalho.css">
```

O primeiro começa o caminho a partir da pasta raiz e o segundo a partir do nível anterior, mas são equivalentes no seu caso.

Comment: O "./" é uma referência à própria pasta do arquivo – é dispensável neste caso.

Answer (score 6):

Uma maneira seria utilizando a tag **[base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)** para definir a url padrão

```
<head>
<base href="http://meu-dominio/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/cabecalho.css">
</head>
```

Desta forma o caminho será o mesmo tanto na página *index.html* quanto na *cadastro.html*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meu-dominio/style/cabecalho.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Como provavelmente você não trabalha com o metodo MVC você será obrigado a escrever `../style/cabecalho.css`, já no index é só usar `style/cabecalho.css`;

Comment: Primeiro, MVC não é um método, mas sim uma arquitetura. Segundo, MVC não tem absolutamente nada a ver com o problema dele. Ele pode usar outras arquiteturas e ser obrigado a escrever da mesma forma proposta por você.

Comment: É verdade guilherme! Usei método como uma palavra mais generalizada.Mas sim o MVC é uma arquitetura.

Comment: Já li sobre MVC, mas fiquei somente na teoria, sou do 1º ano de Ciência da Computação e estou em um projeto para desenvolver um website, se puderem me ajudar com links sobre mvc aplicado a html5/php ficarei grato, eu entendi a lógica dessa arquitetura, mas não como aplicá-la de forma geral